# No media even if I have two SSDs and two hard drives

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, partitioning, ssd

I have two 240 GB SSDs and two 2.0 TB HDDs in a Lenovo [ThinkStation D30 Type 4353](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/thinkcentre_pdf/d30_hmm.pdf) bought refurbished two years ago. In trying to boot Windows 10 my PC from a USB flash drive, it sees no [media at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nghLk.jpg).

[image]

I can see all my drivers when I am with Ubuntu, but not when I try to boot Windows 10. Here is a little picture when I run `sudo fdisk -l` :

[image: Image 2]

[image: Windows installation calling for driver]

I asked this question because during the installation I got that error.  Here's more data:

```
$ lsblk | grep -v "loop" && df -h | grep -v loop
```

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE    RO  TYPE    MOUNTPOINT 
sda     8:0      0  223.6G   0  disk
 Lsda1  8:1      0  223.6G   0  part    /
sdb     8:16     0  1.8T     0  disk
sdc     8:32     0  1.8T     0  disk
 Lsdc1  8:33     0  1.4T     0  part
sdd     8:48     0  223.6G   0  disk
 Lsdd1  8:49     0    55M    0  part
sde     8:64     0  1.8T     0  disk
 Lsde1  8:65     0  9.3G     0  part    /media/jeremie/Win10Update
sr0     11:0     1  1024M    0  rom
```

How can I fix it so that I can see at least my two SSDs? Do you have an idea of the logical boot sequence here?

[image: Boot device selection after POST]

Comment: You probably need the appropriate driver for whatever controller the SSDs and HDDs are connected to. Linux should be able to tell you with the output of `lspci` or something like that. (Or look inside and see what the drives are connected to.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have already used controllers today, i.e. one from IBM and the other from Intel, but none of them worked for me. To be honest, I worked all day in trying to find the solution, but I have no positive answers yet.

Comment: Did you load the appropriate Windows drivers for those controllers? Notice there's a "Load Driver" option at the bottom of that window.

Comment: I used ibm_dd_sraidmr_6.702.07.00-2_windows_32-64.exe, i.e. https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-serveraid-m-series-and-mr10-series-sas-controller-device-driver-v67020700-2-microsoft-windows-ibm-systems and that one https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29350/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-Floppy-Driver-Package?product=55005. Can you tell me if both of them were fine?  I think they are good, but maybe I am wrong

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Do you need information with `lspci`? I can certainly provide them to you, but there's too much info

Comment: @DavidSchwartz When I run the controller, I got "No signed device drivers were found. Make sure that the installation media contains the correct drivers, and then click OK".

Comment: @K7AAY I am supposed to have two 1.8TB HDD and two 240Go SSD. Yeah, we can see three of them, which is weird, but I assure it is two of each, not three.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have modified my question. I think it might be caused by the boot sequence. Can you check the Startup Device menu and tell how the devices must be ordered?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your after Power-On Self Test Boot Options screen and my best suggestions regarding what they are:

[image]

USB Key: USB DISK 2.0 PMAP *is what's on the USB flash drive*
 |- Legacy: USB Disk 2.0 PMAP *is the EFI partition of the USB flash drive*
 L_ UEFI: USB Disk 2.0 PMAP *is the GPT partition of the USB flash drive*
SCU Device 1: Micron_M500_MTFDDAK240MAV *is one of your SSDs*
SCU Device 2: Intel Volume0 *looks like a RAID configuration of the 1.8 TB HDDs*
SCU Device 3: KINGSTON SA400S37240G *is your other SSD*
SATA 0: MATSHITA DVD-RAM SW830 *is your DVD drive*
Network 1: IBA GE Slot 00c8 v1372 *is your LAN adapter for PCE boot use*

SCU Device 2 looks like a RAID configuration never removed from those drives. I would remove those drives, then try to install to SCU Device 1. Once that works, then move ahead in small steps, such as adding the Kingston SSD, then breaking up the RAID pairing of those 1.8 TB drives and adding them back in.

And, as [Tonny](https://superuser.com/users/83250/tonny) wisely noted in a comment, go into the BIOS/Firmware settings and make sure Legacy/CSM Support is disabled there.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. A leftover of a previous raid-config can confuse Windows and not bother Linux at all. I would also recommend the disable "Legacy/CSM" support in the Bios. That might account for the bogus extra disk.